# Pegar extensão oculta de Uri

Tags: java, android, url, mime-type

Tenho um aplicativo para assistir e baixar videos online, meu código detecta o mimetype pela url para usar como extensão do vídeo baixado.

Porém alguns sites tem a extensão oculta, como por exemplo esta url: `http://www.animeplus.org/inc/video.inc.php?&file=NSwzOWE0YWQ5ODhhNWQ4NWEx&token=rm_uJeMTUxNjA4OTM0OQ==` o VideoView consegue reproduzir o vídeo, porem o Downloader pega o mimetype como php e salva o vídeo na extensão php, este é o trecho de código que eu uso para pegar a extensão:

```
String mimeType =  '.' + MimeTypeMap.getFileExtensionFromUrl(url.toString());
```

Neste caso ele pega a extensão do vídeo como deveria: `https://www.blogger.com/video-play.mp4?contentId=6bc99b4dd120f980`

Então, como resolver este problema?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usa das maneiras de capturar o link é acessando a página com a classe [URLConnection](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html) e depois retornando o `Header Response: Location` . Ex:

```
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;

public class HelloWorld
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    try {
        /* Especifica a URL */
        URL url = new URL("http://www.animeplus.org/inc/video.inc.php?&file=NSwzOWE0YWQ5ODhhNWQ4NWEx&token=rm_uJeMTUxNjA4OTM0OQ==");

        /* Abre a conexão */
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

        /* Define um User-Agent. É necessário, caso não adicione essa linha, você receberá um erro 403 (Não Autorizado) */
        connection.setRequestProperty("user-agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/63.0.3239.132 Safari/537.36");

        /* Aqui você captura o Header da resposta. */
        System.out.println( connection.getHeaderField("Location") );

    } catch (Exception e) {
      System.out.println("Erro: " + e.getMessage());
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Mas isto é java SE

Comment: `Java SE` é uma ferramenta de desenvolvimento para a `Java Platform`. Isso é apenas `Java` (como está na tag da pergunta)  e você pode executar o mesmo código no Android.

Comment: Como já suspeitava, isso é java SE, deve ter outras formas de fazer isto no android.

Comment: E tem (afinal de contas isso é Java), basta copiar o `try..catch` e executar esse código com o `AsyncTask`. '-'

Comment: @SamuelIves Java é Java, meu fi.

Comment: java é java mais existem diferentes apis com diferentes comportamentos, android e j2me são ambos feitos em java mas um código feito para j2me não vai rodar no android e vice e verça, assim como o seu código JAVA SE DESTINADO A DESKTOP E NÃO A DISPOSITIVOS MÓVEIS, não rodou pois não é o alvo da plataforma como eu já disse antes

Comment: @SamuelIves Eu fiz um exemplo com Java QUE TAMBÉM SERVE NO ANDROID cara. Você não compreende isso? Pode negativar sem problemas (Boot preto é assim mesmo). Se você se preocupasse em ler a documentação https://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/URL.html e https://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html vai ver que o código que postei (parte dele) **também serve no Android**. #ADSUMUS